# dhcpcd using wrong MAC address on DHCP request

Tags: dhcp

I have 2 rbpi that use the dhcpcd daemon. The second one is using a clone image of the first.

After having detected a problem with DHCP (they got disconnected for long periods of time for no reason), I decided to use tcpdump to find out what was happening. It turns out both are sending rbpi1's MAC address in the DHCP request, which somehow makes sense considering rbpi2 is using a cloned image.

So I removed the files on /var/lib/dhcpcd5 in order to force the daemon to create a new duid, reloaded systemd daemon and forced a system reboot. However the problem is still there.

On the other hand, I don't know why but rbpi2 is somehow winning "the battle of the MACs" and rarely loses connectivity (it must have something to do with the network topology or the DHCP router's cache). That's why I checked again the file /var/lib/dhcpcd5/duid and now the id is based on this rbpi's MAC, as it should be. In fact, regardless of the DHCP requests, every packet sent uses rbpi2's MAC address as it should do.

Why is dhcpcd still using this old MAC address? Where does it come from? I haven't been able to find any other cache/config file where this address is stored. In fact I've opened /var/lib/dhcpcd5/eth0.lease with an hex editor and the MAC stored there is correct (it's rbpi2's MAC).

Answer (score 0):

Check your switches. Had a similar issue. After rebooting the switch problem was solved.

Comment: I'd understand your answer if I was seeing this MAC address at the DHCP server but I see that while running tcpdump at rbpi2 itself.

Comment: Ok, I know what was going on. What I was seeing at rbpi2 were the DHCP requests coming from rbpi1, but a few hours later I could also see rbpi2's, which means it has something to do with rbpi1 or with the part of the network where this is installed. Considering this, your answer might be useful for me. Thanks.